# How do I make a JavaScript Array in PHP going of the last array number id +1?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Okay, I have been searching for an answer for this somewhat trick question. I have a site that runs random Google searches by using a list of JavaScript arrays. I have another site that goes with the other site that allows users to enter in their own search topic. These user entered values go into a giant text file that I like to call, the playground.

What I want to do is make the Php script write the user entered value into a JavaScript array, but use the array number id from the last entered JavaScript array, plus 1.

Example:
The last array entered is `rand[60] = "hello";`
Jon Doe enters `"test"`.
The php script writes into the `topics.js` fie, `rand[61] = "test";`

I already have a file writing script for php...

```
<?php
//Idea Poster
$idea = $_POST['idea'];

//Idea DATA
$data = "$idea \n\n ";

//Idea Writer
$fh = fopen("Ideas.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);

//Closer
fclose($fh);
//Reload Page
$page = "POSindex.php";
$sec = "0";
header("Refresh: $sec; $page");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the writing script as it is, and then write a script to read the .txt file and convert it to a JSON array on-the-fly.

Assuming you want to form a valid JS file:

```
echo 'var topics = ', json_encode(file('Ideas.txt'));
```

**Optimize**

The above script would always read the file and encode the contents into JSON; this can be optimized by keeping a cache file.

```
if (!file_exists('topics.json') || filemtime('topics.json') < filemtime('Ideas.txt')) {
    // changes were made to Ideas.txt
    $topics_js = 'var topics = ' . json_encode(file('Ideas.txt'));
    // update cache file
    file_put_contents('topics.json', $topics_js);
    echo $topics_js;
} else {
    // read from cached file
    readfile('topics.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON array instead. Read the JSON from the file, decode it, add the element to the array, encode it, and write it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just store your data in json format in the first place.

```
<?php
//Idea Poster
$idea = $_POST['idea'];

//Idea DATA
$data = "$idea \n\n ";

//Idea File (contains a json array)
$fh = fopen("Ideas.json", "r");
$contents = fread($fh, filesize("Ideas.json"));
fclose($fh);

// decode json
$ideas = json_decode($contents);
// add the new entry
$ideas[] = $idea;

// write it out 
$fh = fopen("Ideas.json", "w");
fwrite($fh, json_encode($ideas));
fclose($fh);

//Reload Page
$page = "POSindex.php";
$sec = "0";
header("Refresh: $sec; $page");
?>
```

Or, if you really need that file to be single lines of plain text, you can use the php 'file' function to read it in as a php array and then run that through 'json_encode' to get a json array. You might have to do something about the double spacing in the file but basically you should get what you're looking for.